# How to access overlay name with overlayadd or overlayremove in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I need to know the name of the overlay (markers) when i use this code ( http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-overlayadd ) :

```
map.on('overlayadd',function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
map.on('overlayremove',function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

i don't see name param in the result in the console.

Answer (score 2):

When layers are changed through a layer control, events fired have a [layer name property](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layers-control-event).

For regular layer add/remove events, you cannot have layer names, because name is stored internally in `L.LayerControl` object. To have it, you can add a `name` attribute to options map on each layer initialization, so later you could get it with `e.layer.options.name`. For example,

```
var layer = L.tileLayer('http://...',
      { attribution: '© OSM', name: 'Sample Layer' });
```

Comment: the console show me nothing... and for geoJson layers, i do the same ?

Comment: I have done this a couple times, so the error must be somewhere in your core. I cannot solve it without seeing it.